# Jersey RestFul with error 500 and no logs

Tags: java, jpa, jersey

I am trying to code a restful program. To do this I created a Generic Mapper (Mapper.class). When I use it on my class user.class everything is OK but when I change my class to planning.class, I have an error

**User.class**

```
    @Entity
@XmlRootElement
public class Utilisateur implements Serializable{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "UTILISATEUR_ID")
    private int Id;

    @NotNull
    private String Login;

    @NotNull
    private String MotDePasse;

    @NotNull
    private String Prenom;

    @NotNull
    private String Nom;

    @NotNull
    private EnumTypeUtilisateur TypeUtilisateur;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy="Moniteurs", cascade=CascadeType.ALL) 
    private Collection<Planning> Plannings;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy="Moniteurs", cascade=CascadeType.ALL) 
    private Collection<Disponibilite> Disponibilites;

    public Utilisateur(){
    }
    public Utilisateur(String Login, String MotDepasse, String Prenom, String Nom, EnumTypeUtilisateur TypeUtilisateur){
        this.Login=Login;
        this.MotDePasse=MotDePasse;
        this.Prenom=Prenom;
        this.Nom=Nom;
        this.TypeUtilisateur=TypeUtilisateur;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return Id;
    }

    public void setId(int Id) {
        this.Id = Id;
    }
    public String getLogin() {
        return Login;
    }

    public void setLogin(String Login) {
        this.Login = Login;
    }

    public String getMotDePasse() {
        return MotDePasse;
    }

    public void setMotDePasse(String MotDePasse) {
        this.MotDePasse = MotDePasse;
    }

    public String getPrenom() {
        return Prenom;
    }

    public void setPrenom(String Prenom) {
        this.Prenom = Prenom;
    }

    public String getNom() {
        return Nom;
    }

    public void setNom(String Nom) {
        this.Nom = Nom;
    }

    public Collection<Planning> getPlanning() {
        return Plannings;
    }

    public void setPlanningCollection(Collection<Planning>  PlanningCollection) {
        this.Plannings = PlanningCollection;
    }

    public Collection<Disponibilite> getDisponibilite() {
        return Disponibilites;
    }

    public void setDisponibiliteCollection(Collection<Disponibilite> DisponibiliteCollection) {
        this.Disponibilites = DisponibiliteCollection;
    }

    public EnumTypeUtilisateur getTypeUtilisateur() {
        return TypeUtilisateur;
    }

    public void setTypeUtilisateur(EnumTypeUtilisateur TypeUtilisateur) {
        this.TypeUtilisateur = TypeUtilisateur;
    }

}
```

**Planning.class**

```
    @Entity
@XmlRootElement
public class Planning implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "PLANNING_ID")
    private int Id;

    @Column(name="DATE_EVENEMENT")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date dateEvenement;

    @NotNull
    private EnumTypePlanning Type; 

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name="ActivitePlanning", 
            joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="PLANNING_ID", referencedColumnName="PLANNING_ID"),
            inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="ACTIVITE_ID", referencedColumnName="ACTIVITE_ID"))
    private Collection<Activite> Activites;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="GROUPE_ID",insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Groupe Groupe;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name="UtilisateurPlanning", 
            joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="PLANNING_ID", referencedColumnName="PLANNING_ID"),
            inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="UTILISATEUR_ID", referencedColumnName="UTILISATEUR_ID"))
    private Collection<Utilisateur> Moniteurs;

    public Planning(){

    }

    public Planning(Date dateEvenement, EnumTypePlanning Type, Collection<Activite> Activite, Groupe Groupe){
        this.dateEvenement = dateEvenement;
        this.Type=Type;
        this.Activites=Activite;
        this.Groupe=Groupe;

    }

    public int getId() {
        return Id;
    }

    public void setId(int Id) {
        this.Id = Id;
    }

    public Date getDateEvenement() {
        return dateEvenement;
    }

    public void setDateEvenement(Date dateEvenement) {
        this.dateEvenement = dateEvenement;
    }

    public EnumTypePlanning getType() {
        return Type;
    }

    public void setType(EnumTypePlanning Type) {
        this.Type = Type;
    }

    public Collection<Activite> getActivites() {
        return Activites;
    }

    public void setActivites(Collection<Activite> Activites) {
        this.Activites = Activites;
    }


    public Groupe getGroupe(){
        return Groupe;
    }

    public void setGroupe(Groupe Groupe) {
        this.Groupe = Groupe;
    }

    public Collection<Utilisateur> getMoniteur() {
        return Moniteurs;
    }

    public void setMoniteurCollection(Collection<Utilisateur> MoniteurCollection) {
        this.Moniteurs = MoniteurCollection;
    }

}
```

**Mapper.class**

```
public class Mapper<T> extends AbstractFacade implements IMapper<T> {
    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "EJPlanningRestPU")
    private EntityManager em;

    private List<T> list;

    public Mapper(Class T){
    super(T);
        EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("EJPlanningRestPU");
        em = emf.createEntityManager();
    }

    @Override
    protected EntityManager getEntityManager() {
        return em;
    }

    @Override
    public void add(T itemA) {
    ParameterIsNotNull(itemA);  
    super.<T>create(itemA);    
    }

    @Override
    public void update(T itemA) {
    ParameterIsNotNull(itemA); 
    super.<T>edit(itemA);
    }

    @Override
    public void delete(T itemA) {
    ParameterIsNotNull(itemA);   
    super.<T>remove(itemA);    
    }

    @Override
    public T getById(int id) {
    ParameterIsNotNull(id);   
    T item = (T)super.find(id);
    return item;
    }

    @Override
    public List getAll() {  
        list = super.findAll();
        return list;
    }

    @Override
    public void ParameterIsNotNull(Object param){
        if(param == null){
        throw new IllegalStateMessage(param.toString()+" a généré une erreur ! ");
        }
    }
```

**AbstractFacade.class**

```
    public abstract class AbstractFacade<T> {

    private Class<T> entityClass;
            private List<T> list;


    public AbstractFacade(Class<T> entityClass) {
        this.entityClass = entityClass;
    }

    protected abstract EntityManager getEntityManager();

    public T create(T entity) {
        try {
            getEntityManager().getTransaction().begin();
            getEntityManager().persist(entity);
            getEntityManager().getTransaction().commit();
            return entity;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        return null;
    }

    public void edit(T entity) {
        try {
            getEntityManager().getTransaction().begin();
            getEntityManager().merge(entity);
            getEntityManager().getTransaction().commit();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }

    }

    public void remove(T entity) {
        try {
            getEntityManager().getTransaction().begin();
            getEntityManager().remove(getEntityManager().merge(entity));
            getEntityManager().getTransaction().commit();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public T find(Object id) {
        try {
            return getEntityManager().find(entityClass, id);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public List<T> findAll() {
        try {
            javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery cq = getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder().createQuery();
            cq.select(cq.from(entityClass));
            return getEntityManager().createQuery(cq).getResultList();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public List<T> findRange(int[] range) {
        try {
            javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery cq = getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder().createQuery();
            cq.select(cq.from(entityClass));
            javax.persistence.Query q = getEntityManager().createQuery(cq);
            q.setMaxResults(range[1] - range[0] + 1);
            q.setFirstResult(range[0]);

            return q.getResultList();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return null;
        }
    }
    public List<T>findByOneParameter(String Table, Object param){
    CriteriaBuilder criteriabuilder = getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<T> q = criteriabuilder.createQuery(entityClass);
    Root<T> c = q.from(entityClass);
    ParameterExpression<Object> p = criteriabuilder.parameter(Object.class, Table);
    q.select(c).where(criteriabuilder.equal(c.get(Table), p));
    TypedQuery<T> query = getEntityManager().createQuery(q);
    query.setParameter(p, param);
    return list = query.getResultList();

    }

     public List<T>findBytwoParameter(String Table,String Table2, Object param, Object param2){
    CriteriaBuilder criteriabuilder = getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<T> q = criteriabuilder.createQuery(entityClass);
    Root<T> c = q.from(entityClass);
    ParameterExpression<Object> p = criteriabuilder.parameter(Object.class, Table);
    ParameterExpression<Object> p2 = criteriabuilder.parameter(Object.class, Table2);

    q.select(c).where(criteriabuilder.equal(c.get(Table2), p2), 
                      criteriabuilder.equal(c.get(Table), p));

    TypedQuery<T> query = getEntityManager().createQuery(q);
    query.setParameter(p, param);
    query.setParameter(p2, param2);
    return list = query.getResultList();

    }
     public List<T>findBythreeParameter(String Table,String Table2,String Table3, Object param, Object param2, Object param3){ 
    CriteriaBuilder criteriabuilder = getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<T> q = criteriabuilder.createQuery(entityClass);
    Root<T> c = q.from(entityClass);
    ParameterExpression<Object> p = criteriabuilder.parameter(Object.class, Table);
    ParameterExpression<Object> p2 = criteriabuilder.parameter(Object.class, Table2);
    ParameterExpression<Object> p3 = criteriabuilder.parameter(Object.class, Table3);

    q.select(c).where(criteriabuilder.equal(c.get(Table2), p2), 
                      criteriabuilder.equal(c.get(Table), p),
                      criteriabuilder.equal(c.get(Table3), p3));

    TypedQuery<T> query = getEntityManager().createQuery(q);
    query.setParameter(p, param);
    query.setParameter(p2, param2);
    query.setParameter(p3, param3);
    return list = query.getResultList();

    }

    public int count() {
        try {
            javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery cq = getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder().createQuery();
            javax.persistence.criteria.Root<T> rt = cq.from(entityClass);
            cq.select(getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder().count(rt));
            javax.persistence.Query q = getEntityManager().createQuery(cq);
            return ((Long) q.getSingleResult()).intValue();
        } catch (Exception e) {       
            return 0;


}
    }
}
```

**Utilisateur.Mapper**

```
public class UtilisateurMapper extends AbstractFacade  implements IUtilisateurMapper {

   @PersistenceContext(unitName = "EJPlanningRestPU")
    private EntityManager em;
    private List<Utilisateur> list;

    public UtilisateurMapper() {
        super(Utilisateur.class);
        EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("EJPlanningRestPU");
        em = emf.createEntityManager();
    }

    @Override
    protected EntityManager getEntityManager() {
        return em;
    }
    @Override
    public Utilisateur getByPseudoOrMDP(String Table, String field, String Search) {
        Utilisateur user = new Utilisateur();
        list =super.findByOneParameter(Table, Search);
        if(list.size()<=0){
        throw new IllegalStateMessage(Search+" déjà utilisé !");
        }else{
        user = list.get(0);
        }
        return user;  
    }

    @Override
    public Utilisateur getByPseudoAndMDP(String pseudo, String MDP) {
        Utilisateur user = new Utilisateur();
        try{
        list =super.findBytwoParameter("pseudo","mdp",pseudo,MDP);
        user = list.get(0);
        }catch(Exception e){
        throw new IllegalStateMessage("Aucun utilisateur trouvé!");
        }
        return user;  
    }


}
```

**PlanningMapper.Class**

```
    public class PlanningMapper extends AbstractFacade  implements IPlanningMapper{


    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "EJPlanningRestPU")
    private EntityManager em;
    private List<Planning> list;

    public PlanningMapper() {
        super(Planning.class);
        EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("EJPlanningRestPU");
        em = emf.createEntityManager();       }

    @Override
    protected EntityManager getEntityManager() {
        return em;
    }

    @Override
    public Planning getByDateAndGroupe(String Date, String Groupe) {
        Planning user = new Planning();
        try{
        list =super.findBytwoParameter("dateEvenement","Groupe",Date,Groupe);
        user = list.get(0);
        }catch(Exception e){
        return null;
        }
        return user;  
    }

}
```

**Error screen :** 
[500 Error scan][1]

Answer (score 1):

first, please share error logs.

`500 Internal server error` simply mean some exception has been thrown in server and request not completed as expected. So I guess its may be some null pointer exception and the reason might be your invalid JSON or your code logic I am not sure about it.